# Quick question cardinalities and onto mappings

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f: A \to B$, and if $|B| \geq |A|$, does this mean that $f$ can never be surjective or is it the other way around? I used to remember a simple argument that can help me deduce these cases, but I forgot.

Comment: Try a small example: if $|B|=3$ and $|A|=2$, can $f:A\to B$ be surjective?

Comment: If you want to conclude surjectivity is impossible, you will want $|B|\gt |A|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, provided we say $|B| > |A|$.  If $|B| = |A|$, then we could have a surjective function.

Think about it: a function $f$ can never be **surjective** if the number of elements in the target, or codomain, is strictly more than the number of elements in the source, or domain.  This is because functions are *well defined*, so every element in the domain is sent to exactly one element in the codomain.  But there are strictly more elements in the codomain, so they can't all be hit.

Similarly, if $|A| > |B|$, (where $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain), then we can never have an **injection** from $A$ into $B$.  This is because $A$ has strictly more elements than $B$, and every element of $A$ has to go to exactly one element of $B$.  So some element in $B$ must be hit more than once since $A$ has strictly more elements than $B$.